# Keyword errors when trying to get a column from dataframe by using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get one column( which is '날씨' in my csv file). But when I try to get that one column from csv, it keeps getting keyword error. Here is the brief code that I made ..and also there is sentences that shows an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
df = pd.read_csv('seoul.csv', encoding = 'cp949', index_col=0)
del df['지점']
df2 = df['날짜']


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '날짜'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-26-659cfcff0838> in <module>
      7 df = pd.read_csv('seoul.csv', encoding = 'cp949', index_col=0)
      8 del df['지점']
----> 9 df2 = df['날짜']

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '날짜'
```

​

I got a keyword error when I run this, what is wrong and how to fix 
it?
when I use

```
df.head()
```

I can clearly see '날씨' on a result.
[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWbgL.png)

Comment: Can you try to access the column using the index df[[0]] in your case, if you can, it looks like there's a mismatch between the encoding of the column name.

Comment: sadly it doens't work in df[[0]]

Comment: Ah, then you need to reset the index

Comment: You can use `df.dtypes` to know which columns you can deal with, in your case, 3 columns are  in the same level and the fourth `날짜` is an index.

Comment: ty guys It turns out I have some problem design the index lol

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's on the other level of the dataframe, you can see, the column you're looking for is not on the same line as the other columns, try using:

```
print(df.index)
```

Or:

```
print(df.reset_index()['날짜'])
```